# Displacement map from substance painter looks WAY different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, displacement, normal-map

I've drawn this line that affects how the normal/height textures look on substance painter:
[image: Substance painter example]

However, when I import all of this into Blender using the node wrangle, it looks like this:

[image: Blender render]

It doesn't have any modifiers on top of it, and it is also adding this strange, detailed texture on top of it. This is how my node tree looks like. I had to lower scale/strength of the displacement/normal maps from 1 to 0.001 because otherwise it didn't look at all to what I did in substance painter.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: node tree]

Comment: A displacement scale of 1 would, at default settings, mean 1 meter.  So a scale of .001 isn't weird, and it may still be a little high for the paint layer.

Comment: @AllenSimpson thank you! I didn't know it was a value for meters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distortion you see occurs because substance triangulates your model differently than blender does. This stands out more when you have straight uvs and curved surfaces with few loops. This is expected with models optimized for games.

To make the triangulation consistent re-Export from Blender your model to substance with a triangulation modifier on every object(triangulating when it exports) or export your model from substance painter under, file<export<model to get substance's triangulated versions and then import into Blender. I recommend the first, because the second will join any separate objects and has extra steps if you want to make future changes to your model.

Displacement only works in cycles and you are using enough geometry to displace and will only needlessly add to the normal map's effect when used for height.

Comment: Thank you so much! I triangulated it directly on blender and now it looks exactlly how I need it.

I'm pretty new to Blender/Substance so I didn't know what I did mess up.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.