# why are there black artifacts all over my displacement map?

Tags: materials, normals, displacement, height-map

so, i have a 4k height map exported from substance. i apply it, make sure to turn on displacement and bump, and i get this result: [image]

it doesnt matter if i change the scale. see here: [image]

this is what it looks like in substance, looks absolutely nothing like this in blender: [image]

Comment: Is your mesh resolution (in blender) high enough and is the mesh triangulation between blender and substance consistent? See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229794/93111

Also, a displacement scale of 0.5 might be a bit much. Maybe try 0.01?

Comment: changing it to 0.01 doesnt help, it's still has those black artifacts, just less so. id like to retain as high detail as possible and get the most out of my displacement map which is 4k. see result of 0.01 here: https://imgur.com/a/ckeskLK. also, the triangulation suggested does nothing. the resolution is high enough, in fact no matter how much resolution i add, the artifacts only get worse. so i feel like it is working, but its just shading itself wrong for some reason??